# NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "some sting":String

Tags: ruby

My rails app just started receiving this error today. Here is the code context. It is throwing the error on the line that starts with `new_host_id`

```
while @host_ids.include?(new_host_id)
  i++
  new_host_id = duplicate_host_id + i.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby does *not* have a `++` operator.

The idiom in Ruby is `i += 1`, which is the abbreviated form of `i = i + 1`.

---

Initially I thought that the posted code was incorrect and had to be `++i` to generate that error. However, as Jörg W Mittag explains in a comment, this is not the case:

> [..] Ruby allows whitespace (including line breaks) between an operator and the operand(s), so the entire thing is interpreted as `i + (+(new_host_id = duplicate_host_id + i.to_s))` [.. which is] why the NoMethodError refers to String.

Here is a simplified example showing the issue (the posted code refers to the first case):

```
> x = "hello"
> +x
undefined method `+@' for "hello":String (NoMethodError)
> x+
syntax error, unexpected $end
```

I used `+` and not `++` above to simplify the example: Ruby treats `++i` and `i++` as the productions `+(+i)` and [roughly] `i+(+)` ..

Comment: No, that's correct. Ruby allows whitespace (including line breaks) between an operator and the operand(s), so the entire thing is interpreted as `i + (+(new_host_id = duplicate_host_id + i.to_s))` or something like that. That's why the `NoMethodError` refers to `String`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks, I can't believe I missed over that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'm curious as to why i++ was working in a production environment for 2 months before this error occurred...

Comment: @Paul Jorg's comment contains the key. This "works" (as in there is no Exception), but doesn't do what is expected: `a = 0; a++\nb = 2` - it is treated as `a = 0; a + (+(b = 2))`. In this case `b = 2` evaluates to `2` and integers have `+@`. However, the final value of `a` is still 0. The result of `a + (+(2))` -> `a + (2)` -> `0 + 2` -> `2` is *discarded* and there is *no* increment occurring.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the error was caused by the previous line `i++`

I changed `i++` to `i = i + 1` and it's working now.

Here's the working code

```
while @host_ids.include?(new_host_id)
  i = i + 1
  new_host_id = duplicate_host_id + i.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had warnings on, you'd probably have got a warning about that line.

```
$VERBOSE = true
def foo
  i = 2
  i++
  j = 5
  j + i
end

warning: possibly useless use of + in void context
```